# Unique constraint violated due to value too large for column (Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hibernate

Is it possible to get an

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX) violated

dueto an

> ORA-12899: value too large for column (XXX)

in an oracle database using Hibernate (as is stated in [this confluence page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unique-constraint-violation-due-to-value-too-large-for-column-214860926.html))?

**(The columns for each error are in different tables but relatad to each other)**

In that case, how is this possible?

*** UPDATE ***

I can confirm the causal relation between the exceptions. The given scenario is as follows:

The are a number processes that perform different operations to the database. This operations are stacked until Hibernate session flush. When you invoke the flush method, the queries are performed in the same transaction.

In my particular case I have the entities A and B that both have inside an entity C (the reference of the entity is the same, there is no copy for each father entity). When the program tries to save A (with a string field too large), first executes the C insert query, and then the insert to the entity itself that leads to a "ORA-12899: value too large for column". At this point C is in the database but not yet commited.
Then the next process tries to save B that contains a C entity and this leads to "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" on C entity.

My questions are:

- When the first process doesnt have errors (no column too large) the second one doesnt try to insert C again, only make the insert to entity B (probably detached state of the entity C?).
- Why the execution is not aborted on the first error?

Comment: First error is too generic, hard to identify without detailed message. Second one may occur if you try to store >10000 chars in a column of VARCHAR type (should use CLOB instead)

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko yes, the second error is due to an attempt of storing a string larger than the one defined in the database. But my question is, that error can cause the first one in any way?

Comment: It sounds like the bug report is saying that a particular applicatoin (Confluence) encounters a value that is too large, attempts to handle that exception, and fails to do so correctly/ completely causing the unique constraint error.  That's a bug in Confluence.  It doesn't mean that Oracle itself is thowing a constraint violation exception when the value is too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both exceptions (unique constraint and value too large for column) are related. There are serveral processes executed in a single transaction. Those processes make calls to the methods save() or saveOrUpdate() stacking queries until the flush() of the Hibernate session or commit the transaction.

At some point a flush() of the session is invoked with the given scenario:

Entity A and B both contains the same reference of entity C. The first process tries to insert entity A, so first executes the insert of C without problem, later tries to insert A but fails due to a too large column exception. At this point C is in the database (not yet commited) but the hibernate session is in an incoherent state due to the previous fail and Hibernate doesnt know about C being inserted (a fail on session flush doesnt trigger a rollback, is responsability of the developer).

Then a second process is executed and tries to insert B into the database. If the previous process went ok, Hibernate only inserts the entity B because he knows C is already in the database. Due to the incoherent session state, Hibernate tries to save the C entity again in the database raising a unique constraint exception.